# Сохранение класс присвоенного при помощие js

Tags: javascript

Есть такой скрипт:

```
   $(function(){
        $('.button').click(function(){
            $('.block').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
```

Где:
.button – класс объекта, по которому кликают.
.block – класс объекта, в который нужно добавить класс.
active – класс, который добавляется или удаляется по клику.

Как сделать так, чтобы класс или его отсутствие запоминал браузер?

Comment: Попробуйте записать при клике в localstorage или в cookies значение блока и есть ли класс или нет. И при следующей загрузке проверяете значение в localstorage/cookies.

Comment: я бы с удовольствием, но я не умею, я читал про localstorage но мне знаний не хватает

Comment: Наверно я не так выразился ,что бы после перезагрузки  браузера, когда вернулся на сайт, сохранялся присвоенный класс

Comment: @l2banners [ru.stackoverflow.com: как использовать localstorage и cookie](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464204/Кто-может-доступным-языком-объяснить-как-использовать-localstorage-и-cookie/464211#464211)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно дополнить ответ тем, что вас интересует сохранение состояния после перезагрузку страницы.

Как уже правильно подсказали у вас два варианта:
1) localStorage
2) cookies

localStorage в ie меньше 9 работать не будет, но думаю сейчас это не является проблемой.

код грубо будет такой:

```
$(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.block').toggleClass('active');
        localStorage.setItem("blockIsActive", "true");
    });
});
```

ну и потом проверяем:

```
var blockIsActive = localStorage.getItem("blockIsActive");
if (blockIsActive == "true") {
    $('.block').addClass('active');
}
```

как-то так

Comment: Поставил вот так, но не работает, что я сделал не так?

Comment: <script>

$(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.block').toggleClass('active');
        localStorage.setItem("blockIsActive", "true");
    });
});



var blockIsActive = localStorage.getItem("blockIsActive");
if (blockIsActive == "true") {
    $('.block').addClass('active');
}
</script>

Comment: @l2banners, внесите код внутрь функции `$(function() { [код здесь] [изначальный код здесь] });`

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("blockIsActive", $('.block').hasClass('active'));`

Comment: Просто супер! То что надо, спасибо большое!

Comment: вот вам примерчик - [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2o4j8fz/1/)