# Как вызвать функцию по клику и вернуть её значение переменной?

Tags: javascript

Пытался вызвать функцию и присвоить возвращаемое этой функцией значение переменной, однако у меня выдается синтаксическая ошибка **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**:

```
$('.bpt-heart').on('click', let myFunc = function (){
   return '123';
});
console.log(myFunc())
```

Как вызвать функцию по клику и передать возвращаемое ей значение переменной?

Comment: `let myFunc = `  вот это в коде зачем?

Comment: В данном случае вы пытаетесь присвоить функцию к переменной

Comment: и зачем куда-то что-то возвращать? почему нельзя внутри что-то сделать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, мне нужно переменную this положить в localStorage, а если вызвать localStorage без this, а только по селектору, то он отработает на всех селекторах

Comment: как связан текущий вопрос с какими-то this и localstorage внезапно появившимися?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477282/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-js), мне нужно вывести this за пределы функции, чтобы localStorage снаружи его обработал

Comment: Почему нельзя обработку внутри функции?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, она просто не отрабатывает
`$('.bpt-heart').on('click', function (){
        $(this).toggleClass('Active');
        let IsActive;
        if ($(this).hasClass('Active'))
        {
            IsActive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsActive = false;
        }
        localStorage.setItem("blockIsActive", "true");
        var blockIsActive = localStorage.getItem("blockIsActive");
        if(blockIsActive == "true")
        {
            $(this).addClass('Active');
        }`